# unchecking show menubar by default in new terminals won't save

Tags: 11.10, configuration, gnome-terminal

I am unchecking "Show menubar by default in new terminals" in gnome-terminal so that I can use Alt+f and Alt+b to move back and forth the text without raising the menu, but it won't save. Once I have closed the terminal and open a new one, the menu is back there again.
Any ideas?

This seems to be a bug to me, so I have opened one in Launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/880739

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For gnome-shell users that want a workaround for this bug but want to preserve global menus in Unity then perhaps a better solution is to create a file /etc/X11/Xsession.d/81ubuntu-menu-proxy with the single line content:

```
[ "$DESKTOP_SESSION" != "ubuntu" ] && unset UBUNTU_MENUPROXY
```

---

http://shebang.brandonmintern.com/oneiric-upgrade-breaks-readline-alt-b-and-alt